# External Services - Timeout Limit

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, oauth2, namedcredentials, external-services

I am working on an integration where I am using external services and a screen flow to call an external API and display the result to the user. In Apex you can set the timeout of an API call to a maximum of 120 seconds. Is this possible with external services and flows? My API takes 40-60 seconds so I plan to have a spin wheel for the user until the result is returned (any other suggestions welcome).

Comment: have you go the answer for the question?

Comment: No. But i'm assuming since external services are based on apex behind the scenes, its the same as apex time outs. The other option is just to test